# Django-Calling python script in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I have a python script written up that returns a list of values from a database. I want to incorporate that script into my django website that I have created. I have an html file right now in my templates folder that has dictionary values hardcoded but how do I replace the dictionary hardcoded material with the script, lets call it values.py

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropDown = [" ", "Run1", "Run2", "Trail1", "Trail2"];
    var dropDownID = [" ", "111111", "222222", "333333", "444444", "555555"];
    $("#dropDown").select2({
        data: dropDown
    });

    $("#dropDown").change(function() {
        $("#dropdownID").val(dropDownID[$("#dropDown option:selected").index()]);
    });
});
```

Now do I just add my values.py into my templatetag folder and then from there do  I just fill the 
`var dropDown = [" ", "Run1", "Run2", "Trail1", "Trail2"];` to something like

```
var dropDown = [
    {% load tag %}
    <div id="id_div">
        {% value %}
    </div>
]
```

Comment: it is not clear what you're asking for. Do you want to put data generated within Django into template so that you can use it from javascript (json.dumps will help)? Are you trying to load data dynamically?

Comment: @Marat Sorry if its confusing I want to put the data loaded from the python script into the javascript dropdown menu. Want to replace the hardcoded portion of my dropdown with a list that gets loaded from the python script, dynamically

Comment: In this case, you need to create a view that will return this data in JSON, pull it by jQuery.getJSON and put into the variable. I'm not sure what parts you need to be explained

Comment: @Marat all of it, if you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

Create a view to generate this data:

```
# views.py
import json

def getdropdown(request)
    mydata = ...
    return http.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(mydata),
        mimetype='application/javascript'
    )
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropDown = [];
    // ...
    $.getJSON("<url of the getdropdown view>", function(data){
      dropDown = data;  
    })
    // ... r async call
})
```

Comment: so where would I call my python script values.py? And would the url for the getdropdown be something liike this myapp.polls.views?

Comment: You mentioned Django in the question title, so I assumed you're familiar with it. This snippet supposes that you move code from `values.py` into django views (namely, to getdropdown, to this part:`mydata = ...`). If you do not run a django website already, your question is much broader and involves running an HTTP webserver, choosing a framework etc.

Comment: my django website is up and I put my `values.py` into a templatetag folder and then I should call it in my views.py correct? But what do I fill in for the `mydata =...`

Comment: ok, I see. I'm pretty sure this tutorial will answer all of your questions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
var dropDown = {{dropDown|safe}};
```